# Описание схожих классов Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Нужно описать 2 класса, подскажите правильно ли я это сделал? Если нет подскажите как сделать правильно.
Заранее спасибо.

```
public interface Transport { public void go(); }

public class Car implements Transport{
  private String color;
  private Double price;
  private int age;
  private int speed;

  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public Car(String color, Double price, int age, int speed) {
    this.color = color;
    this.price = price;
    this.age = age;
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  public void go() {
    System.out.println("Понеслась!");
  }

  public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
  }
}

public class Motorcycle implements Transport {
  private String color;
  private Double price;
  private int age;
  private int speed;

  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }


  public void setSpeed(int speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  public Motorcycle(String color, Double price, int age, int speed) {
    this.color = color;
    this.price = price;
    this.age = age;
    this.speed = speed;
  }


  public void go() {
    System.out.println("Поехали!");
  }

  public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    Car volvo = new Car("Red", 520000.00, 7, 90);

    System.out.println(volvo.getSpeed());
    volvo.go();

    Motorcycle scorpio = new Motorcycle("Green", 320000.00, 3, 75);

    System.out.println(scorpio.getSpeed());
    scorpio.go();
  }
}
```

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Используйте принципы ООП. У вас у обоих сущностей одинаковые поля и методы, различается лишь поведение в методе go, кроме того вы не используете интерфейс в классе Main.

```
public interface Vehicle {
    void go();
    int getSpeed();
    int getAge();
    double getPrice();
    String getColor();
}

public abstract class Transport implements Vehicle {
    private final String color;
    private final Double price;
    private final int age;
    private final int speed;

    public Transport(String color, Double price, int age, int speed) {
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
        this.age = age;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vehicle car = new Car("Red", 520000.00, 7, 90);
    Vehicle moto =  new Motorcycle("Green", 320000.00, 3, 75);

    List<Vehicle> myTransport = Arrays.asList(car, moto);
    for (Vehicle vehicle : myTransport) {
        vehicle.go();
        System.out.println(vehicle.getSpeed());
    }

}

private static class Car extends Transport {
    public Car(String color, Double price, int age, int speed) {
        super(color, price, age, speed);
    }

    @Override
    public void go() {
        System.out.println("gogo car");
    }
}

private static class Motorcycle extends Transport {
    public Motorcycle(String color, Double price, int age, int speed) {
        super(color, price, age, speed);
    }

    @Override
    public void go() {
        System.out.println("gogo moto");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!, попробую лучше разобраться, я думал что сделал все по принципу ООП.